# Java double initialization

Tags: java, double, declaration

In what way are these statements different?

1. double dummy = 0;
2. double dummy = 0.0;
3. double dummy = 0.0d;
4. double dummy = 0.0D;

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Having tried a simple program (using both 0 and 100, to show the difference between "special" constants and general ones) the Sun Java 6 compiler will output the same bytecode for both 1 and 2 (cases 3 and 4 are identical to 2 as far as the compiler is concerned).

So for example:

```
double x = 100;
double y = 100.0;
```

compiles to:

```
0:  ldc2_w  #2; //double 100.0d
3:  dstore_1
4:  ldc2_w  #2; //double 100.0d
7:  dstore_3
```

However, I can't see anything in the Java Language Specification *guaranteeing* this compile-time widening of constant expressions. There's compile-time *narrowing* for cases like:

```
byte b = 100;
```

as specified in [section 5.2](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html#5.2), but that's not quite the same thing.

Maybe someone with sharper eyes than me can find a guarantee there somewhere...

Comment: Could you suggest a good resource where one can read about what ldc2_w and the other instructions mean?

Comment: ldc2_w pushes a two-word constant value onto the operand stack. ldc2_w takes a single parameter, <value>, which is the two-word item to push.
Source: http://asmsupport.github.io/jvmref/ref-ldc2_w.html

Answer (score 21):

For the first one:

```
double dummy = 0;
```

the integer literal `0` is converted to a double with a widening primitive conversion, see [5.1.2 Widening Primitive Conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2) in the Java Language Specification. Note that this is done entirely by the compiler, it doesn't have any impact on the produced bytecode.

For the other ones:

```
double dummy = 0.0;
double dummy = 0.0d;
double dummy = 0.0D;
```

These three are exactly the same - `0.0`, `0.0d` and `0.0D` are just three different ways of writing a `double` literal. See [3.10.2 Floating-Point Literals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.2) in the JLS.

Comment: what about `0d`?

Comment: @J'e still exactly the same, just one more way to write a `double` literal.

Answer (score 3):

The last 3 should be identical. The literal on the right side is a double already. The 'd' or 'D' is implicit when you have a decimal literal.

The first one is slightly different in that 0 is an int literal, which will be widened to a double. I don't know if that even produces different byte code in this case or not; the result should be identical anyway.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I know the results are identical, I want to know the differences under the hood.

Comment: For "0.0", "0.0d" and "0.0D" there are really no differences under the hood. Those are three ways to write a double literal, they all are exactly equivalent.