# Java double initilization with 0

Tags: java, initialization, double

I recently came across some code where double are initialized the following way:

`double nb = 0.;`

A very similar question has already been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443331/java-double-initialization) but doesn't cover this specific case. Are there any benefits or special behavior of such initialization?

Comment: What is special about the initialisation? Are you asking about the trailing `.`?

Comment: Yes, I assume it is egal to ```0.0``` but I was wondering if there is any difference

Comment: No, no difference.

Comment: Oh, one more thing, `.0` works as well.

Comment: I see, thank you for the extra information

Comment: Why does Java allows values like `.0` and `0.`?

Comment: @Smile why shouldn't it?

Comment: @Shredator also, [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.2) is the formal specification for how to represent a floating point (i.e. `float` and `double`) literal

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca thank you again, should have checked this page before asking.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Thanks, your answer clears it. I hadn't read the formal specification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`0.` is a perfectly legal `double`, and has the same value as `0.0`

You can test it with `jshell`

```
jshell> 0. == 0.0
$1 ==> true
```

[Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.2) is the formal specification for how to represent a floating point (i.e. `float` or `double`) literal

The gist of it is that these are all valid ways to represent a `double`

```
1e1
2.
.3
0.0
3.14
1e-9d
1e137
```